# Advance filter failing to work as part of worksheet_change(by Val)

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to automatically update a graph once set criteria are change using advance filters.

There are three specific cell that set the criteria range on a separate sheet that is meant to then filter on these new values which then produce the updated graph..

i.e. 
I am trying to use an advance filter on Sheet B (Graph Sheet) from data taken from Sheet A (Summary Sheet) when set cells change in value on Sheet A which will update a graph on Sheet A that takes the data from the filtered table on Sheet B

Unfortunately the code below (also using the alternative entry looking at the table rather than set range of cells) isn't completing the advance filter as required even when, if I run it separately, the advance filter code does appear to filter the table (and thus update the graph)

Any help would be appreciated...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Worksheets("Summary Sheet").Range("O5:S6")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

Sheets("Graph Sheet").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A7:S1002").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("G1:I2"), Unique:=False
Sheets("Summary Sheet").Select

End If

End Sub
```

Alternative Code

```
Sheets("Graph Sheet").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("Filter[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("G1:I2"), Unique:=False
Sheets("Summary Sheet").Select
```

No error messages appear upon the code 'running' but the table is not filtered on the required values

Comment: After a little bit more playing with the code I appear to have found a solution. The code was looking at Sheet A for the advance filter criteria (which is blank data) and all I needed to do was to add the sheet to CriteriaRange...

Comment: Unqualified `Range` calls are member calls against `Me`, i.e. the `Worksheet` module that code is written in (would be implicit/indirect reference to `ActiveSheet` otherwise). Don't `Select` sheets, declare a `Worksheet` variable and `Set` it to the sheet object you mean to work with, then use that variable to qualify the `Range` member calls that mean to work against that particular worksheet.

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon , I'm fairly new to working with VBA so it isn't very elegant but will work to update it with your advice. Much appreciated thanks :D